# Length of a string in c# WinForm

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a text box in my form and I want to check if the first char is equal to something,
basically I want it to do this :

```
if(Textbox1.text.length(0) == "a")
{
  do stuff
}
```

Comment: so???? what is problem ??

Comment: is says I cant use like a method

Comment: try this 
if(textBox1.Text.Substring(0,1)=="a")
{//do stuff}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eh, are you looking for

```
  if (Textbox1.Text.StartsWith("a")) {
    // do stuff
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Can't believe it took this long for this to be posted. People suggesting `Substring()`? lol...

Comment: @DGibbs, what's wrong with `Substring()`? Probably `Startswith` kind a does substring behind the scene.

Comment: @Rahul Why would you use the wrong tool for the job when much better options are available? Yeah it would work, however this is exactly what `StartsWith()` was built for, it also checks for `null` or empty strings. And I couldn't find any [evidence to support your claim regarding the StartsWith() implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,1c787ba07a7b11ab) though this does show the extra kinds of checks going on when using it compared to just chucking out a `Substring(0,1) == "a"` and calling it a day.

Answer (score 3):

.length only returns an integer of length of the string.
This will compare the first char with 'a'.

```
if(Textbox1.text[0] == 'a')
```

Comment: When  `Textbox1.text == "";` (empty string) the code will fail.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by two ways...
one i mentioned in your question's comment
second is

```
if(myTextBox.Text[0] == 'B')
{
//do studd
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try smething like this:

```
Textbox1.Text.StartsWith("a") ? do something : do something else;
```

and if it is not just about first character then try something like:

```
Textbox1.Text.Contains("a") ? do something : do something else;
```

Answer (score 0):

if(textBox1.Text.Substring(0,1)=="a")